# Cant access data in a subclass inside array object

Tags: java, arrays, object, subclass

Good afternoon people,
I have this code:

Object Camiao:

```java
   public class Camiao {

    private String codigo;
    private int contaKm;
    private int capacidade;
    private String unidade;
    private tipoCamiao tipoMotor;

    public Camiao() {
    }

    public Camiao(String codigo, int contaKm, int capacidade, String unidade) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.contaKm = contaKm;
        this.capacidade = capacidade;
        this.unidade = unidade;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public int getContaKm() {
        return contaKm;
    }

    public void setContaKm(int contaKm) {
        this.contaKm = contaKm;
    }

    public int getCapacidade() {
        return capacidade;
    }

    public void setCapacidade(int capacidade) {
        this.capacidade = capacidade;
    }

    public String getUnidade() {
        return unidade;
    }

    public void setUnidade(String unidade) {
        this.unidade = unidade;
    }
}
```

Subclass Cisterna:

```java
public class Cisterna extends Camiao {

    private String subTipo;

    public Cisterna() {
    }

    public Cisterna(String codigo, int contaKm, int capacidade, String unidade, String subTipo) {
        super(codigo, contaKm, capacidade, unidade);
        this.subTipo = subTipo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the subTipo
     */
    public String getSubTipo() {
        return subTipo;
    }

    /**
     * @param aSubTipo the subTipo to set
     */
    public void setSubTipo(String aSubTipo) {
        subTipo = aSubTipo;
    }
}
```

Subclass Mercadorias:

```java
public class Mercadorias extends Camiao {

    /*public enum subTipoCamiaoMercadorias {
        na, ba;
    };*/
    private String subTipo;

    public Mercadorias() {
    }

    public Mercadorias(String codigo, int contaKm, int capacidade, String unidade, String subTipo) {
        super(codigo, contaKm, capacidade, unidade);
        this.subTipo = subTipo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the subTipo
     */
    public String getSubTipo() {
        return subTipo;
    }

    /**
     * @param aSubTipo the subTipo to set
     */
    public void setSubTipo(String aSubTipo) {
        subTipo = aSubTipo;
    }
}
```

Where i add my information to array:

```java
switch (codCamiao2) {

case "CI":camiao[i] = new Cisterna(linha[0], Integer.parseInt(linha[1]), Integer.parseInt(linha[2]), linha[3], linha[4]);

case "BT":camiao[i] = new Camiao(linha[0], Integer.parseInt(linha[1]), Integer.parseInt(linha[2]), linha[3]);

case "FG":camiao[i] = new Camiao(linha[0], Integer.parseInt(linha[1]), Integer.parseInt(linha[2]), linha[3]);

case "MC":camiao[i] = new Mercadorias(linha[0], Integer.parseInt(linha[1]), Integer.parseInt(linha[2]), linha[3], linha[4]);

}
```

I add my information using my subclass object Cisterna and Mercadorias;
I add information using my main object Camiao;

My problem is that i can access my GET's and SET's in Camiao, but i cant access my GET's and SET's in Cisterna and Mercadorias.

I use this code to write, but i need .getSubTipo()

Code

```
System.out.println(camiao[x].getCodigo() + "|" + camiao[x].getContaKm() + "|" + camiao[x].getCapacidade() + "|" + camiao[x].getUnidade() + "|");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have any instance getters/setters in the subclasses `Cisterna` and `Mercadorias`.
The field `subTipo` in `Cisterna` and `Mercadorias` is static - that is, shared between all instances of `Cisterna` and `Mercadorias`.  Possibly, this is the error, and you need to remove `static` modifier from `subTipo` field and related getter/setter methods.

Also, you need to use `break` after each `case` statement!

```java
String codigo = linha[0];
int contaKm = Integer.parseInt(linha[1]);
int capacidade = Integer.parseInt(linha[2]);
String unidade = linha[3];
String subTipo = linha[4];

switch (codCamiao2) {
case "CI":
    camiao[i] = new Cisterna(codigo, contaKm, capacidade, unidade,  subTipo);
    break;
case "BT":
case "FG":
    camiao[i] = new Camiao(codigo, contaKm, capacidade, unidade);
    break;
case "MC":
    camiao[i] = new Mercadorias(codigo, contaKm, capacidade, unidade, subTipo);
    break;
}
```

Comment: its an error, i didnt saw that. Im gonna remove it. Thanks

Comment: i dont have any get/set? I dont understand, can you clarify please.

Comment: I updated my answer - there's also an issue in your `switch` statement

Comment: do you know how i can i acces my .getSubTipo() from my array?

Comment: i need to write my info and use it in other parts, who can i do that?

Comment: I meant, that when you declared `subTipo` as static, its getter/setter were also static, not referring a specific instance - only this.  Thus, all _instance_ getters/setters used to be provided by the parent class `Camiao`.

Comment: As you have array of `Camiao` objects, you'll be able to use getSubTipo() only if you check the specific type and do explicit cast.
```if (camiao[i] instanceof Cisterna) { String subTipo = ((Cisterna) camiao[i]).getSubTipo(); }```

Comment: Possibly, it's worth to improve design and move `subTipo` to the parent's class, thus making `Cisterna` and `Mercadorias` redundant.

Comment: I tested it and it works, im gonna see if it work for the rest of the tipes.

Comment: It works just fine. thank you bro you are my savior

Comment: Just an idea - to avoid casting you simply override `toString()` method in your classes and provide output of `subTipo` field only in the subclasses.
Then you can call `System.out.println(camiao[x]);` and it will be printed in a polymorphic way.

Comment: i did that before, but i just want to know to do this way because i have more options in my program that i need to use that getSubTipo, so i cant do that because some times its just to select the tipes of Camiao